# War File not deploying properly with Jenkins

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins, build, war

With the Jenkins, My Build is completed successfully and has used source code management from Git.I am using maven to build my project.But the war file is not deployed properly.
The Tomcat users.xml file has this content:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

This is the stack trace of error :

**

```
[INFO] Building war: /root/.jenkins/workspace/First Maven project/target/hfcl.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.329s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 08 16:49:20 IST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/279M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/First Maven project/pom.xml to HFCL/HFCL/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HFCL-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/First Maven project/target/hfcl.war to HFCL/HFCL/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HFCL-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
channel stopped
Deploying /root/.jenkins/workspace/First Maven project/target/hfcl.war to container Tomcat 8.x Remote with context HFCL
  [/root/.jenkins/workspace/First Maven project/target/hfcl.war] is not deployed. Doing a fresh deployment.
  Deploying [/root/.jenkins/workspace/First Maven project/target/hfcl.war]
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/root/.jenkins/workspace/First Maven project/target/hfcl.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:184)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:998)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:976)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:736)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:682)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1072)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:627)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1764)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:542)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/HFCL] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:715)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:761)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:101)
    ... 18 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/HFCL] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:715)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:761)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:184)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:998)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:976)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:736)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:682)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1072)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:627)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1764)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:542)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**
The configurations in Tomcat for jenkins is as follows :

[image]

Can anyone suggest what i am missing ?

Comment: check with providing "/" in front of HFCL in Context path..Tomcat 8 may have some inbuilt problem..try with tomcat 7.x version once.

Comment: tried but no results.

Comment: Have you tried with Tomcat 7??

Comment: yes,it's getting deployed with the tomcat.